# Why does this bash command work when I run it normally in a shell but fail through Python's Popen?

Tags: python, bash, kali-linux

I want to spawn a terminal in Kali with python, then send manipulate the terminal window.

So I can spawn a new terminal and get its pid in Python:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT, check_output
p1 = Popen(['x-terminal-emulator'])
print(f'pid: {p1.pid}') // 31700
```

then pass it to [`xdotool`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xdotool.1.html) like:

```
xdotool search --pid 31700
```

stdout:

```
90177537 // first code given isn't the one to use
88080390 // second one seems to work, not sure why
```

and then pass that back to `xdotool`:

```
xdotool windowfocus 88080390
```

success! I can move the window around, pass it input, etc.

But when I try to combine all this into the Python code, the `xdotool search --pid 31700` command fails:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT, check_output
p1 = Popen(['x-terminal-emulator'])
print(f'pid: {p1.pid}')
window_id = check_output(['xdotool', 'search', '--pid', str(p1.pid)])
```

error:

```
pid: 548
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/jonat/Documents/Github/net-vis/python/scanner.py", line 6, in <module>
    window_id = check_output(['xdotool', 'search', '--pid', str(p1.pid)])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 528, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['xdotool', 'search', '--pid', '548']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're likely trying to look for windows before the process has had time to open one. Try adding a second long sleep before invoking `xdotool`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got a race condition. There's an interval between when the `x-terminal-emulator` process starts running and when it actually brings up a window and is discoverable using `xdotool`.  Simply adding a short wait in your code makes it work for me:

```
import subprocess
import time

p1 = subprocess.Popen(['x-terminal-emulator'])
print(f'pid: {p1.pid}')
time.sleep(2)
window_id = subprocess.check_output(['xdotool', 'search', '--pid', str(p1.pid)])
```

Or instead of a sleep, use a polling loop to wait until `xdotool` is successful, possibly with some sort of timeout:

```
import subprocess
import time

p1 = subprocess.Popen(['lxterminal'])
print(f'pid: {p1.pid}')

t_start = time.time()
while True:
    try:
        window_id = subprocess.check_output(['xdotool', 'search', '--pid', str(p1.pid)])
        break
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        t_delta = time.time() - t_start
        if t_delta > 5:
            raise
        time.sleep(0.1)

print('got window id:', window_id)
```

The second solution will give you much better response time.